# for loop in html is causing jquery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a webpage about games. In this there is a page in which categories of games should be diplayed, when one is clicked, the games within this category should then appear underneath it.

This is an extract from the html file, I believe the issue is arising when i use the  and  tag. As they stay constant through each iteration, when i click one category, all categories display their repsective games, rather than just the one selected.

```
               {% if games %}
                   <h1> Games</h1>
               {% for catergory in games %}
                   <highlight><strong><toggleButton>{{ catergory.0.get_catergory_display }} </toggleButton></strong><highlight>
                   <ul>

                       {% for game in catergory %}

                                <catGames><li><highlight> <a href="/panda/game/{{ game.slug }}">{{game.name}}</a> : <i>
                                   {% if game.rating != -1 %}
                                       {{game.rating}}
                                   {% else %}
                                       unrated
                                   {% endif %}
                               </i></highlight></li></catGames>

                       {% endfor  %}

                   </ul>
                   <br/>
               {% endfor %}
           {% else %}
               <strong> There are no games present.</strong>
           {% endif %}
```

here is the jquery file

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('toggleButton').click(function() {
    if ($('catGames').is(':hidden')) {
        $('catGames').show();
    } else {
        $('catGames').hide();
    }
});
```

});

I was wondering if there was an easier solution than having to manually type out each category, and getting rid of the for-loop. It is also causing problems with the jquery  which highlights the text being hovered over, lighting all of the categorys and games, rather than just the one being hovered.

Answer (score 0):

No the problem is not about loop. Its about how you create elements inside loop and its about how you reference them with onlick even.

so this is one way to fix is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('toggleButton').click(function() {
        if ($(this).parent('highlight').next('ul').find('catGames').is(':hidden')) {
// this way you try to point to the corresponding ul tag next
// to the toggle botton and try to hide and show the whole ul

            $(this).parent('highlight').next('ul').find('catGames').show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent('highlight').next('ul').find('catGames').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

So About section you said is there a better solution for the category and opening and closing categories yes there is. Have you checked https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/. I believe you can use the functionality and customized it based on your needs. If you had problem using it let me know.

Comment: no i'm afraid that doesn't work, the categories now, when clicked, don't show any of the games.

Comment: @AdamChristie. My answer was about the reason why it does not work and a possible work around you may need to change it a little but to meet your needs. + i think you can look for other ways to do it more clean. but for now i updated my answer please check is this one is working

Answer (score 0):

You have to specific what is the right `<catGames>`

Try this different way :

**First one :**

```
$('toggleButton').click(function(e) {
  const cat = $(e.currentTarget).closest('h1').next('ul').find('catGames');
  cat.is(':hidden') ? cat.show() : cat.hide();
});
```

**Second one (best way for me) :**

Wrap each catergory with a `<div class='catergory'>` for example and try this :

```
$('div.catergory').on('click', 'toggleButton', function(e){
  const cat = $(e.delegateTarget).find('catGames');
  cat.is(':hidden') ? cat.show() : cat.hide();
});
```

`$(e.delegateTarget)` focus the main container whose contain the `<catGames>`

Comment: The first solution should be wrong cause its gonna only point to first ul and so we will have the first category being shown and hidden whenever user clicks on other toggle buttons

Comment: The second solution works in that it now only highlights the one being hovered over. However, when a category is clicked, it does nothing, rather than revealing the catGames, any idea why this might be?